# DexException on ionic build

Tags: android, plugins, ionic-framework

I am working for a ionic app and trying to run

```
ionic build android
```

when it check for `:dexDebug` , it throws an error  and building is not complete. The error it gives is :

```
 com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/deepak/projects/ionic/pajh_new/platforms/android/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/home/deepak/projects/ionic/pajh_new/platforms/android/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
```

Error Code:
    2
  Output:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/ReserveIntents;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I found a solution that it raised due to two dependencies referring to same class and and dependencies are added to build.gradle of android platform file  but i could not resolve that